# How to select a record by key from Kafka Streams KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka Streams and trying to understand its architecture. The name of KTable (or GlobalKTable) suggests that this data structure allows for random-access querying of underlying data - this is basically what a "table" means in regular database systems. However, in Streams documentation I can only find information on querying local "state stores" ([here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html)), but not KTables. Therefore, the question is, whether Kafka Streams allow for selecting arbitrary records from a KTable by key, equivalent to

```sql
SELECT value FROM table WHERE key = 'abc';
```

Yes, I know this is possible with ksqlDB.

Comment: Ksql goes the way of querying remote state stores, by the way

Comment: Guess I'm not really understanding the question. As the documentation says, only way to query a Ktable is to register it with a named state store, which you then lookup by name and fetch keys from